# Github Codespaces - Could not detect the platform/language from repo

Tags: vscode-devcontainer, codespaces

I'm trying to open [this](https://github.com/aniongithub/nativelibrary-dotnet-core) repository using Github Codespaces. Note that this repository is [correctly configured](https://github.com/aniongithub/nativelibrary-dotnet-core/blob/master/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json) for local [devcontainer](https://github.com/aniongithub/nativelibrary-dotnet-core/blob/master/Dockerfile) development.

However, when I try to open it in CodeSpaces, it seems to build the container correctly, but fails with:`Could not detect any language/platform in the source directory` (full log [here](https://gist.github.com/aniongithub/6639d9cf88a254fbd401de0ba231e4c5#file-creation-log))

What am I missing?

Comment: Same issue here with another repo. The Oryx error message comes from here: https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/a09410ab72c54829d8fd5f9f47591656940f903e/src/BuildScriptGenerator/DefaultPlatformsInformationProvider.cs, but I don't get why the platform cannot be detected

Comment: Try using MCR base image instead of stock `ubuntu` image from Docker Hub, e.g. `mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:bionic`.

Comment: @BerkantIpek But why? I'm keen to understand what's going on, not just using base images that are incompatible with my workflow.

Comment: @Ani better see this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/blob/main/containers/CODESPACES.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have run into a regression that Codespaces had during the time specified in your log file.

Given your configuration, Oryx should no longer run, which means you should no longer run into this issue.

Would you mind retrying?

Comment: I tried this with a few of my repositories and it works well now. Thanks!